# Can we get non-zero value for certain $f(x)$ in the following integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\left[\int f(x)dx \right]^{}_{x=0}$$

Here we integrate $f(x)$ and put $x=0$ in the result.

Can we get non-zero value for certain $f(x)$ ignoring the constant term? If yes, can you give some examples?

Comment: If the integral in []'s is indefinite, you are free to choose an additive constant that will give the desired result.  If the integral is definite, please specify the limits of integration.

Comment: I don't think you asked the right question. An antiderivative can be any differentiable function and differential functions can take any values at $x=0$ (or elsewhere).

Comment: "ignoring the constant term": this doesn't make sense, general functions don't have a defined constant term.

Comment: He meant the constant of integration.

Comment: @Narasimham: the constant of integration is also immaterial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $f(x)=e^x$. What we get is: $\int e^x dx = e^x + C, e^0=1$ (assuming $C=0$).

Comment: $  \int a e ^{ b x} $ in general..

Comment: Yes, I understand. I just thought the question was about to introduce a specific simple example.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer clearly satisfies the OP, but the question itself suggests a misunderstanding of "the constant term".

The expression 
$$
\int f(x)dx
$$
represents a large set of functions. Any two of the functions in the set differ by a constant, so you can choose one of them, say $F(x)$ (your favorite), and then write all the others as
$$
F(x) + C 
$$
for some value of $C$.

In elementary calculus there is usually a well known favorite. For polynomials you make the constant term  $0$. The favorite is the just plain $e^x$ in @arcquim 's answer. But you could just as correctly write
$$
\int e^x dx = (e^x -1) + C .
$$

That would be a little weird, but not wrong. So in the original question the wish to "ignore the constant term" doesn't really make sense.

Comment: We can assume that the OP understands the constant term as a $+C$ term explicitly appended to a closed-form expression. He should consider the case of $\log(x)+\log(2)$ vs. $\log(2x)$ where the constant can be "absorbed" in the function.

Comment: Another example where the constant is ambiguous:$$\int \frac{-1}{\sqrt{1 - u^2}} du = \cos^{-1} (u),$$ but also $$\int \frac{-1}{\sqrt{1 - u^2}}  du= -\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - u^2}}  du= -\sin^{-1} (u).$$These two functions differ by $\pi/2$ (a constant), but it's hard to make an argument for one of them having a "constant term" added while the other one doesn't have a "constant term".

Answer (score 0):

The notation for an indefinite integral

$$\int f(x)\,dx$$ does not denote a unique function, but a set of functions that differ in a constant function, and this is why we write

$$\int f(x)\,dx=F(x)+C,$$ where $C$ is left unspecified.

Hence,

$$\left.\int f(x)\,dx\right|_{x=0}=F(0)+C,$$ which can have any value. Or more rigorously, it doesn't have a value !